# Animate same element in different time with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some issues for some time now. I´m trying to make this work but  I tested one of the things didn't work or didn't work as aspected. In this case the callback doesn't work.
I need to have three animations, one of them with a callback, with different times on the same element.

```js
$('#hey').animate({
  'margin-left': '100px',
}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});

$('#hey').animate({
  'margin-top': '100px',
}, {queue: false, duration: 1500}, function() {
  alert('hey'); // <-- this doesn't work -->
});

$('#hey').animate({
  'height': '190px',
}, {queue: false, duration: 2000});
```

```css
#hey {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hey"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`complete`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) property

```
$('#hey').animate({
    'margin-top': '100px',
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 1500,
    complete: function () {
        // Callback here
        alert('hey'); // In your case...
    }
});
```

Please also note that SO is not an alternative to reading the documentation yourself

Comment: You are right until certain point. But note, if all the users read the documentation e didn't have 90% of the questions posted on SO.